# Unable to Boot into Windows 7 After Installing Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, 16.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I have a HP Pavilion HPE desktop with 3 harddrives installed.

Windows 7 was originally installed on the machine. I then installed Ubuntu 16.04,onto the second drive attempting to dualboot both OS. Since installing Ubuntu, I have been unable to boot into windows 7.

1. On boot, the GRUB loader shows only the Ubuntu 16.04 options. No Windows options.
2. I have tried a few GRUB update and detection commands
3. Going to BIOS and selecting boot options to boot from Windows HD shows the message - "Boot disk not found please check"
4. When I boot into Ubuntu 16.04, In Files, I can see the Windows Drive with all previous files showing.
5. You can see an attached image of the drive configuration from my **[fdisk output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIu7L.png)** in ubuntu

Does anyone have potential steps to enable booting into Windows?

I am looking to boot into or recover windows files and configuration. I am willing to uninstall or remove Ubuntu if that can solve this issue.

Harddrives:

- HD 1 - Windows 7 was installed on
- HD 2 - Ubuntu 16.04
- HD 3 - Should be empty

Comment: Have you tried `sudo update-grub` to see if it's recognizing the windows 7 when `grub` configs are re-created?  If windows was hibernated, or fast-boot was enabled; it may be ignored (*as file-system won't be clean*)

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 will reach end of life on April 30, at which point you will need to upgrade.  Windows 7 already reached end of life over a year ago.  If I were you, I would say that now is a good time to install supported versions of both operating systems. After April 30, new questions about 16.04 will be off topic.

Comment: @guiverc I have tried `sudo update-grub` unfortunately that does not add Windows to the menu.

Comment: @Nmath Updating may be an idea. I have some specific Ableton and music production configuration I would like to ensure I can transfer over to any updated OS. Any recommendation on migrating Windows data? Or at least making it bootable again before I make changes?

Comment: In my prior comment I'd suggested one reason it won't be recognized by `update-grub`, if you `mount` the partition, have you looked up the logs to see if error conditions were mentioned (such as a RO only mount occurring).  Mounting at terminal is probably faster than looking up logs (the messages that reach logs appear on screen)

Comment: Is Windows 7 on sda? That is gpt, so Windows would only be UEFI install? But most Windows 7 installs were BIOS/MBR. Did you install Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode? UEFI and BIOS are not compatible, once you start booting from UEFI boot menu, you cannot switch modes. Or grub can only boot other installs in same boot mode.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in `Terminal` :  `sudo update-grub2`
`